# PHP form redirect (header) in external php file not working

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

I have a form on my homepage, which when submitted runs an external form.php file containing the code below. I am testing on MAMP and the header redirect doesn't seem to be working the url is just stuck on the form.php url? I have previously had an echo function which worked fine!? What am I doing wrong? Please help, many thanks in advance

```
 <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$robots = $_POST['robots'];
$from = 'From: Blah Register Form'; 
$to = 'sofi.smith@blah.com';
$subject = 'Blah Lead';

 $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n company: $company\n ";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $robots == '')  {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    header("Location: http://google.com");
exit;
} 
else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again</p>'; 
} 
}
else if ($_POST['submit'] && $robots != '') {
echo 'Sorry, we don\'t like spammers here!';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Is that the whole code in that page?

Comment: Unrelated: Please sanitize your code before using in production.

Comment: Do you have any output before the `header()` function is called?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: the only other code is the doctype etc, that is an external php file that is triggered by the submit button on my index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're condition will not always resolve to true in both scenarios. So unless you know for sure that the email is being sent, you don't know if any of the code is being called. This tightens it's up a bit:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($robots == '') {
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            header("Location: http://google.com");
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong, please try again';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, we don\'t like spammers here!';
    }
} else {
    echo "submit was not set";
}
```

Because right now you have:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] && $robots == '') {
        // send the email or whatever
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $robots != '') {
    echo 'Sorry, we don\'t like spammers here!';
}
```

which means that if `$_POST['submit']` is not set, neither condition would be true.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a space before the first php tag, and you shouldn't close php tags either. That space means that content is sent before header.

However, your header statement can be failing due to several reasons (headers already sent, warning, etc). One quick dirty workaround is to use javascript for that matter:

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<script>location.href="http://www.google.com";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If he will delete the space, most likely that the header will work, so he won't be needed to use JS.

Comment: but in that case it wouldn't enter the header condition, just skip to the *else*. Mail doesn't raise exceptions, it just returns TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: There is no space, it was just an extra space from when I was inserting it into the text editor

Answer (score 0):

First of all write `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then you can see the exact error on page.

Also as i can see mail function it should be `mail( $to , $subject , $message, $additional_headers  )`

I guess there is error in mail function thats why the header function is not working

Comment: Why you voted in negative manner. As i can see there is problem with mail function.

Comment: I hate when downvoters do not care to comment. Have a +1 for solidarity. However, **"From: me@domain.com"** is valid as $additional _header parameter, so no error there.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $company = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['company']));
    $robots = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['robots']));
    $from = 'From: Blah Register Form'; 
    $to = 'sofi.smith@blah.com';
    $subject = 'Blah Lead';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n company: $company\n ";

    if($robots == '') {
        $mail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);

        if($mail) {
            header('Location: http://google.com');
            exit();
        } else {
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again</p>'; 
        }
    } else if($robost != '') {
        echo 'Sorry, we don\'t like spammers here!';
    }
}
?>
```